# After SUDO APT install, how to modify the installed files with root:root permission

Tags: apt, sudo

In our org, we allow only "sudo apt-get" for a normal user. Now the problem is with those files created after this installation are with root:root permission, where this user cannot modify.

Appreciate if you share how you solved this problem using visudo. Let me know if you have any question.

Thanks

Shameer

Comment: First, this is apt-get install, which I dont know which all files are created. Second, this user only has sudo permission to run apt-get not for chown. Anyway to do using sudo settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chown` to change ownership of files and folders. The syntax is:

```
sudo chown <user>:<group> /path/to/files
```

So for example, if you wanted to make the user "john", the owner of `~/myfile.txt` you would run:

```
sudo chown john:john ~/myfile.txt
```

The same goes for folders, however if you need all folders and subfolders changed at once, you would use the `-R` flag, like so:

```
sudo chown -R john:john /path/to/my/directory
```

(You can use `pwd` to find out the current directory)

This will work for any file and folder on the system, however you ***should not*** do this on system files or it can damage the entire OS (many programs depend on ownership and permissions being set correctly). However if there are files and folders that are incorrectly owned by `root`, you can use the above commands to change ownership of them.

Comment: First, this is apt-get install, which i dont know which all files are created. Second, this user only has sudo permission to run apt-get not for chown.

Comment: @santony The system administrator is the one that needs to run the `chown` commands. Also, you can use `apt download` followed by `dpkg -x` to extract the package locally and then you'll be able to see where all the files are installed to. So `apt download` the package, then run `dpkg -x <packagename>.deb extracted`, and look in `extracted` folder. You will see all the folders and files that the package would install. (may need to `mkdir extracted` before you can extract to it first).

Comment: Thank you Daniel, wont solve the problem completely.

Comment: I am wondering if there is an option to run sudo APT install as another user(not root) and then be this user and runas in a common group, so 660 would help this user to edit the file. Would somebody help in those aspects how to do in visudo, i am not a super expert here.

Comment: You can run a command as a different user using `su <username> -c "<command>"`. You will be prompted to enter that user's password. However I'm not sure if `apt` will allow that user to install packages. But to allow them to edit the files, `chmod` them to `664`, then add another group that will be allowed to edit the files (for example: tmpgrp) with `sudo groupadd tmpgrp`, then add the target user to that group with `sudo adduser <username> tmpgrp`, and then run `chgrp` on the files to change group access: `sudo chgrp tmpgrp /path/to/file`. Then the user in `tmpgrp` will have write access